# Killing specific, unresponsive page in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

It only takes a single busy/buggy page to make Google Chrome and XP unresponsive.

Since each page in Chrome is a process, I guess all it'd take is to kill that given process, but even Process Explorer doesn't display the title of each page:

[image]

Does someone know of a way to find which page is busy and kill its process?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome has its own task manager that shows the page name. You can open it by either right clicking on the window title bar and choosing Task manager, or by pressing Shift+Escape.

Comment: Thanks for the great info. SHIFT+ESC works, but I don't understand what you mean by "clicking on the window title bar": Right-clicking on any open page (New Tab, Reload, etc.) doesn't simply any item called "Task Manager".

Comment: Clicking next to open tabs, in the area between the open new tab button and the minimize button opens offers a task manager button. A screen shot I found is here: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-UWiP_KGakto/UFtw4Q8QajI/AAAAAAAAARA/v8g3DGAdM1Q/s1600/Task+Manager+1.jpg